# Are there utility methods for performing unsafe arithmetic in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, hash, unsafe

I'm overriding getting a hash code. There's a point where

```
Hash = 1210600964 * 31 + -837896230
```

which causes an `OverflowException`. Is there a method that I can use, something like:

```
Hash = addUnsafe(multiplyUnsafe(1210600964, 31), -837896230)
```

Without needing to link my project to another assembly? I do not want to remove overflow checks. `dllimports` are OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding GetHashCode in VB without checked/unchecked keyword support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654227/overriding-gethashcode-in-vb-without-checked-unchecked-keyword-support)

Comment: @sstan no, this is asking for a system API that allows unsafe arithmetic.

Comment: by unsafe, I assume you mean that you want your code to allow arithmetic overflows without throwing an exception, right?  If so, then that's what the C# keyword `unchecked` accomplishes, but that VB.NET doesn't have native support for.  The thread I linked provides ways around that limitation in VB.NET.  Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the maths with 64-bit numbers instead and then use `And` to cut off any excess:

```
Option Infer On
' .....
Shared Function MultiplyWithTruncate(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim x = CLng(a) * CLng(b)
    Return CInt(x And &HFFFFFFFF)
End Function
```

Although, as you can mix C# and VB.NET projects in one solution, it might be easiest to write a class in C# to do the unchecked arithmetic, even if you are not keen on adding a reference to another assembly.

It might even be a good idea to write the functions in C# too so that you can test that the VB functions return the expected values. It's what I did to check the above code.

Edit: I was prompted by Joseph Nields' comment to test for performance, and it turned out using CLng instead of Convert.ToInt64 and And works faster.

Comment: It might just be easier to define `Const mask = &HFFFFFFFF` and return `CInt(x And mask)` which will always fit in `Int32`

Comment: This solution did not work for me, an OverflowException was still raised. &HFFFFFFFF is -1 for signed integers. Using &H7FFFFFFF (aka Integer.MaxValue) worked, though.